# Django Custom ModelBackend access cookies

Tags: python, django

I've a custom user model with my own auth backend

How i need a access to cookies in def get_user

How it can be done?

```
class AuthBackend(ModelBackend):

    def authenticate(self, request, **kwargs):
        login = request.POST.get('username')
        login = kwargs['username']
        password = kwargs['password']
        logger.info(password) 
        try: 
            auth_user = Company_Users.objects.get(auth_login=login)
            hash_password = hashlib.sha512(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
            if auth_user.auth_password == hash_password:
                auth_user.is_active = True
                auth_user.is_authenticated = True
                return auth_user
        except Company_Users.DoesNotExist:
            pass
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        ### here i need cookies info <----------------- HERE
        try:
            user =  Company_Users.objects.filter(pk=user_id).first()
            if user is None:
                return None
            return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found the solution:
add middleware function

project_name/settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
     ...add last line..
    'app_dir.file_name.def_name'
]
```

app_dir/file_name.py

```
def def_name(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        # Code to be executed for each request BEFORE
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        CODE GOES HERE 

        response = get_response(request)
        # Code to be executed for AFTER request


        return response

    return middleware
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access cookies in *views* using:

```
request.COOKIES.get('cookie_name', None)
response.set_cookie('cookie_name', 42) # No expired date = until browser close
```

when request is a parameter of the view function and response is `HttpResponse` from 'django.http'.

Comment: get_user doesn't take that arguments

Comment: i need access cookies BEFORE views

Comment: from where you call 'get_user'?
cookie is in the user laptop, you can access it from a `request`, so it have to be derived from a view.(imho)
maybe you meant session?
but this is a completely other question.